# Select every image from a string using php and add lightbox attribute

Tags: php

I'm trying to find a way for getting all the `<img`-tag from an unknown string using php and adding lightbox attribute for each of them.
I tried with this method:

```
preg_match_all('~<img.*?src=["\']+(.*?)["\']+~', $content_universal[0]['text'], $urls);
$urls = $urls[1];

$str = $content_universal[0]['text'];

foreach ($urls as $key => $value) {
    echo $value;
    $newStr = preg_replace("#<img (.+) />#isU", "<a href='{$value}' data-lightbox='image-1'><img $1 style='width: 70%'  /></a>", $str);
}
```

This returns the last `<img`'s source and adds it in the href attribute for every single image in the string.
What I'm trying to do, is to get every replaced image its OWN source for its href.

Comment: have you tried `DOMDocument`? Can you show the `$content_universal[0]['text']` contents?

Comment: its a string got from a CKeditor, it contains something like: "textextextex <img src="/images/ect.jpg"> textextextex <img src="/iamges/blabla.png"> textextex. but on every single page this $content_universal is different.

Comment: `$urls = $urls[1];` is valid if you expect only one match from your regex. print_r($urls) immediately after the `preg_match_all` to see what you receive.

Comment: this is the result of print_r($urls): Array ( [0] => /images/uploaded/Buton%20blog%20interni.jpg [1] => /images/uploaded/Customer%20Service.jpg )

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to get this work. If anyone is interested:

```
$html = str_get_html($content_universal[0]['text']);
foreach ($html->find('img') as $element) {
    $src = $element->src;
    $newStr = str_replace($element, "<a href='{$src}' data-lightbox='image-1'>$element</a>", $html);
    $html=$newStr;

}
echo $html;
```